# Is there any way to stop a particular CAN message coming from an external device on the bus in CANoe?

Tags: can-bus, canoe

I am looking to test a scenario, how my software will respond to disconnection of a particular CAN message coming from an external device. This external device will send many CAN messages in the bus, so I cannot control it to stop just a particular message.
Therefore, I am looking for a way in CANoe just to stop one particular CAN message coming into the bus.
Please need your suggestions here.
I tried to provide as much information here, if more is require kindly put in the comment. Thanks.

Comment: You need to apply a filter for the id/payload in question.

Comment: How do I do that because I am not simulating the node here, I am using the actual DUT connected to the bus. Is there any means to filter messages coming from the real device using CANoe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to split the bus into two and configure CANoe to act as a gateway:

You need a network interface with two CAN channels.
You connect your DUT to one channel (say CAN2) and the remaining bus to the other channel (CAN1).

You then configure both busses in CANoe and add a node to both busses in the simulation setup.

This node should listen to all messages received on CAN1 and output them to CAN2 and vice versa.

If you want certain messages not to reach CAN2, you have to adapt the logic of this node.

Refer to [this article](https://support.vector.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0011376) in the Vector knowlegde base on how to setup a gateway between two CAN busses and how to control the message flow between those busses.

Comment: Thanks M.Spiller.