# Is there any way to stop a particular CAN message coming from another real ECU to DUT (real ECU) on the bus through CAPL scripting?

Tags: function, automated-tests, capl, canoe

I am trying to create a **CAPL script** (test module) to automate my testcases. In the system (test setup) we have all the real ECU's connected with Device/ECU under test. I have came across this function **ILDisableMsg(messageName)/testDisableMsg(msgId)** in CAPL which will block/stop a particular message from simulated node(IL node). Similarly, is there any way to block/stop a particular message from real ECU to DUT receiving it through CAPL script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to stop a particular CAN message coming from an external device on the bus in CANoe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986707/is-there-any-way-to-stop-a-particular-can-message-coming-from-an-external-device)

Comment: Hi, In my case I have 4 CAN channels and DUT is connected to 2 CAN channels.

Comment: Which does not really make a difference, right? What can be done for one channel, can also be done for 2, 3 or even 4 channels.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the correct way is to stop the physical connection with the real ECU. You could use:
TestSetEcuOffline： Used to ECU Disconnect from the bus
TestSetEcuOnline ： Used to ECU Connect to the bus

But, this will stop the whole communication with the real CAN bus channel.
To avoid such situation, try to stop sending internal signals that map your can massage from the SW side.

Don´t forget also to either stop IL block or remove the simulated massage from the configuration!